# 1 constructor arguments specified but no matching constructor found in bean, Why auto-wire byname doesn't work with constructor-arg

Tags: java, spring

**How can I set emp Id as well as its address, And I also want to keep autowire = "byName" for address.**

> Please avoid answering by `<constructor-arg ref="address">`

Below is my scenario

**spring-config.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


    <bean id="empBean" class="com.spring.SpringCoreIOC.autowiring.Employee"
        autowire="byName">
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="int" value="11111" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="address" class="com.spring.SpringCoreIOC.autowiring.Address">
        <constructor-arg value="Secret Chowk" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Address.java**

```
public class Address {
    private String place;

    public Address(String place) {
        super();
        this.place = place;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return place;
    }
```

**Employee.java, class has its own id, int type and address Address type**

```
public class Employee {

    private Address address;
    private int id;

    public Employee(int id, Address address) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.address = address;
    } }
```

**Error I am facing is as below**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'empBean' defined in class path resource [autowiring_byNameByTag.xml]: 1 constructor arguments specified but no matching constructor found in bean 'empBean' (hint: specify index and/or type arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

Thanks in advance!!.

Comment: Check this link with example https://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-bean-autowire-byname-bytype-constructor-and-default-example#constructor
Looks like you need to set autowire="constructor" for `Employee` bean

Comment: great thanks lvan, Got it.

Comment: May i know reason whyautowire="byName" doesn't work with constructor arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `autowire="byName"` and want to pass `id` argument to a constructor, then you should use a constructor with just `id` argument: `public Employee(int id)` and set your address via setter:

```
public class Employee {

    private Address address;
    private int id;

    public Employee(int id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    } 

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Because `autowire="byName"` doesn't work with constructor arguments, but `autowire="constructor"` does.

Comment: thanks for your guidance, Kirill Simonov!, May i know reason whyautowire="byName" doesn't work with constructor arguments?

Comment: @Lokesh Because when autowiring by name spring looks at the properties names. Actually all autowiring modes (except `constructor`) use properties. Take a look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_beans_autowiring.htm)

Comment: @Lokesh Absolutely right. Also note that when autowiring in constructor mode spring looks on arguments types, not names. And if there is not exactly one bean of the constructor argument type in the container, a fatal error is raised.

Comment: correct, i have formatted this as new answer so others could not get confuse in future!!

Answer (score 1):

For more:
I would like to reflect my understanding which I understood by link referred  by Ivan, Kirill.

> `<autowire="byName">`     In this case it is watching student class
>   properties, like id="address" as address is property of Student;
>
> ```
> <bean id="studentBean" class="com.lokesh.SpringCore.entity.Student" autowire="byName"/>
> <bean id="address" class="com.lokesh.SpringCore.entity.Address">
>         <constructor-arg value="EARTH" />
> </bean>
> ```

while in

> `<autowire="constructor">`    it is considering constructor-arg,
>   properties doesn't matters

```
<bean id="studentBean" class="com.lokesh.SpringCore.entity.Student" autowire="constructor">
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="12444" />
</bean>

 <bean id="anything" class="com.lokesh.SpringCore.entity.Address">
        <constructor-arg value="EARTH" />
    </bean>
```

Please correct me or add your point if I am not covering any aspect.

Thanks!!